# Is it possible to play music with a PIC16F628A

Tags: pic, audio, music, pcm

Is it possible to generate and send PCM audio from a PIC16 (or an arduino/atmel)? It does have an analog port, so it should work right? 
And if it does, is the PIC fast enough to generate the clockspeed necessary to play an MP3 for example?
Also is there a way to generate or capture raw PCM data to be send out over the analog port?
Has anyone ever done something like this or any hints on how I get my hands on PCM music?
Also since analog voltage can't be amplified using a transistor, what would be a simple way to increase the voltage?

Comment: *Also since analog voltage can't be amplified using a transistor* So for the last 30 years where I was using transistors to amplify voltages, those little b******s were just faking it! Damn! So all those LM386 audio amplifier modules out there that hobbyists use to amplify an audio signal don't really work. They had me fooled!

Comment: I suggest that you go search on the internet and look for projects where someone uses a PIC or Arduino to play mp3 files. Observe how the **working** ones use a **separate chip** to actually play the mp3 data. Yes the PIC has an analog output but can it do 16 bit at 44.1 kHz sample rate, which is what your mp3 files probably use? Nope! Also that much data is more than a PIC or Arduino can handle.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I don't even think this specific PIC has an analog output. The only analog block the datasheet seems to mention is a comparator. There isn't even an ADC. One could use PWM, but OP won't be able to make more than beeping noises whith that.

Comment: As far as I know transistors are only on or off. So they can only shut off or switch on a voltage. So how can a transistor change the analog signal strength?

Comment: By your second answer you mean not even an arduino can be used as a makeshift audio synthezier/player? Then what does an audio chip have an arduino or PIC doesnt?

Comment: Transistors are **not** merely on/off switches.  They can also operate in a linear fashion.  This is something that you can easily discover.  [The wikipedia article on transistors mentions that transistors are used for amplification.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor)

Comment: I will, that is quite the revelation

Comment: You'll need a little external circuitry, but it should be possible to at least play .WAV files (probably not MP3). For PIC24 parts (I know this isn't exactly what you're using) [here](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-16-Bit-PIC-Microcontrollers-Learning/dp/1856178706) is a good book with an example of playing audio from an SD card

Comment: @dim why do you think PWM would only produce beeping noises? You can definitely reproduce fairly good quality audio with just a PWM, resistor, and capacitor. See the book referenced in my previous comment

Comment: @ks0ze With a 8-bit CPU running at 20MHz and needing at least 4 clock cycles per instruction and which, given the amount of memory it has, will obviously have to fetch the samples from an external chip, but there is no builtin memory controller so you'll have to bitbang the interface? Well, good luck.

Comment: Not sure what bitbang means, but the PWM to analog converter sounds interesting, thanks

Comment: @dim it's been a couple of years but, yes it is totally feasible (at least on the PIC24 which OP doesn't seem tied to PIC16). I've actually gone through the exercise outline in the book and have been able to read a fat16 file system from an SD card over SPI and play a .WAV file out using PWM...

Comment: @ks Of course, with the appropriare MCU, it is totally feasible, and PIC24 is much more capable. OP explicitly mentioned PIC16F628A right in the title, and I'm 100% sure you can't do it with this specific MCU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not without any external circuitry. Some reasons:

- Both do not have a DAC, so you need at least two of these (for stereo), and of at least 16 bit to get some decent quality.
- Probably much more than a few 100 bytes for the PIC or 2 KB SRAM is needed to decode MP3s.
- The CPU speed is not likely to be high enough to process decoding MP3s (not sure of this statement).

There exist specific MP3 shields for Arduino like [Adafruit MP3 shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12660):

[image]

Comment: Yeah I just realized the arduino can only read analog not write it and the PIC can only compare voltages. I guess beepers it is then.  Thanks for pointing me though

Comment: You are welcome, what Arduino has is writeAnalog(), but what it actually does is sending a PWM signal.

Comment: Yeah thats why I was confused. I guess there is large compenents necessary to generate true analog signals that take up to much space for an MCU

Comment: Well actually not, you can quite easily connect a DAC to a PIC or Arduino (never tried myself), so generating some 44 KHz/16 bit sound is not difficult, but probably the processing power and certainly the data buffer storage is out of spec for an Arduino or Pic for MP3 decoding.

Comment: can I just upload a short 5 seconds pcm sample and play that?

Comment: Probably regarding processing power yes, but you need to stream it from a device that is fast enough and coping with a 'stream buffer' of a few hundred to 2 KB SRAM, which is really small.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linear transistor amplifier. The full output of a DAC will be way too large for this amplifier. At +9v battery, this circuit has gain of about
180X. Inputs (from left bottom pin) bigger than 0.01 volt will have some distortion, which may be OK for your learning purposes. If you want to use the DAC signal, then attenuate with the 10Kohm potentiometer (variable resistor).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQW7bI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The feedback network assures us the transistor is always in the linear region.
Learn about feedback.

There now is a 2nd transistor, used to boost the current and thus drive a speaker. Expect maybe 50 milli Watts of power.

Comment: Thanks. I assume there still needs to be a DAC in the top left corner to generate and unamplified audio signal? Or does this already convert PWN Square waves into sinewaves?

Comment: This circuit had GROUND (the bottom triangle) plus the TOP: power from a battery or CLEAN power supply; you provide the CLEAN music at the VIN pin. And you get the output from VOUT. Which will not drive a earphone nor a speaker.

Comment: >And you get the output from VOUT. Which will not drive a earphone nor a speaker.  Isnt that the point of a speaker? If it won't drive a speaker and needs the analog signal, what is it for? Ot did you mean the clean music origin signal from the audi chip wont drive a speaker?

Comment: Amplifiers have many purposes. The amplifiers in your WIFI radio will not drive speakers; they will amplifier 1 microvolt radio signals. I will add a buffer.

Comment: So this will take a weak analog music signal or make it louder, right? And why would it still be weak when It gets 3V? shouldn't that be more than enough?

Comment: Read about loadlines, a key part of how an amplifier functions. The output cannot be larger than the power-supply/battery voltage. Thus a 3 volt battery does not ensure a big output signal.

Comment: I have a little PC speaker powered by 2 AA batteries and that one is plenty loud. Or what do you mean by "big enough output signal" Do you mean it cannot produce enough curent?

Comment: Note the schematic has a volume control at the left, a voltage amplifier in the middle, and a current amplifier on the right. Because the adaptive biasing of Q1 has purpose of hold the collector of Q1 near VDD/2, the voltage across the collector resistor R2 will also be VDD/2. Should you operate the voltage amplifier at 1.5 volts, you will get a small amount of amplification (0.5 * VDD/0.026 = 30X). At VDD = 6 volt, expect 120X. At 18 volts, expect 540X. You might use a standard 9 volt battery (which must provide 5milliAmp to the voltage amplifier, and use the potentiometer to change gain.

Answer (score 0):

For playing short samples, you can actually get specialised sound playing chips, designed for musical greetings cards, doorbells etc.

The PIC16F628A is pretty terrible for this because it has neither an analogue output nor anywhere near enough storage for the music, nor is it particularly fast. It's vaguely comparable to an Atari 2600, although with a 16-bit datapath.

As a beginner, you will probably want a separate amplification stage using either some transistors (google "class A" or "class B" amplifiers). Class D is more efficient and in some ways more suitable for direct digital drive, but it's not quite as beginner-friendly.

You could pick a microcontroller with builtin DAC, e.g. one of the larger STM32 parts: http://embedded-lab.com/blog/stm32-digital-analogue-converter-dac/